# salesforce sandbox as backup and push to sandbox from eclipse

Tags: sandbox

I took backup before refreshing sandbox now i need to push case object custom fields, apex class, pages to sandbox from Eclipse.
I tried with deploy to server by keeping work online and it didnt work

Comment: Did you explicitly ask Eclipse to deploy your files? Selecting to work online doesn't perform a deployment by itself.

Comment: i installed force.com through eclipse i am deploying to sandbox